# Unable to create release build after updating play services to 8.3.0

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow

Unable to create Release APK after updating play services to version 8.1.0 or 8.3.0 I am getting following exceptions.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this.

```
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef
2 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':project:dexRelease'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Even I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: Same here with play services 8.4.0 and proguard 5.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Please see this [Android issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187483).

It's a known bug. The official workaround is:

> The development team has fixed the issue that you have reported and it
>   will be available in a future build.
>
> Workaround for time being: Right the issue is that you need to put the
>   useLibrary element if you need to compile against it. But if you don't
>   compile your code against it but you have 3rd party libs that use it
>   and you run through proguard (Which is picky about wanting to see all
>   the classes that are used), then we need to pass it to proguard
>   whether you ask for it for compiling or not.
>
> The short term work-around is to ask for the library for compiling
>   (which will then also add it to the classpath that we give to
>   proguard).

It basically means you should either recompile all libraries (including third-party libraries) with the latest Google Play Services or revert to an older Google Play Services version.

Comment: Any tips on identifying 3rd party libraries that depend on Play Services? When I upgrade to Play Services 8.x, the "External Libraries" feature of Android Studio indicates there is no dependency on a different version. Running gradle's depenencyInsight also doesn't point to any 3rd-party dependencies on Play Services (./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency gms).

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same error message. In my case it was related to [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).

I wasn't using any third-party libraries that depend on Google Play Services, so Codos answer was useful but didn't solve the problem for me.

It turned out that a static factory method on an interface caused this issue:

```
public interface Foo {
  static Foo get() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Removing the static method from the interface and doing a clean/rebuild solved the problem for me.

According to the documentation there are known issues with static interface methods: [Retrolambda Known limitations](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda#known-limitations)